# If I have if() statements nested in a for() loop, does a break; within them apply to the for() loop?

Tags: java, nested, break

Nothing to add beyond the question provided in the title...

Example:

```
for(...) {
     if(...) {
         if(...) {
             //doing stuffs
             break;
         }
     }
}

//does that break statement get me to this spot?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, it will break out of the `for` loop. `break` will break from loops (such as `while`, `do/while`, `for`) and `switch` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `break` will break out of the for-loop. `break` doesn't break out of if-statements.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.** Because `break` doesn't work for `if` statements. Therefore, it will work for the next loop encountered.

**Note:** `break` is used to terminate loops (`for`, `while`, or `do-while`).